# CSS animation with time interval

Tags: css

I want to rotate a graphic element infinitely but with some time interval by step.

For example, rotate 90 degree (smooth animation) then after 5 secs rotate another 90 degree and repeat the same infinitely.

Can this be done using only css?

Here is my [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ULiFoyo/7/edit)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pretty simple. The following code limits the transformation to keyframes `40%-60%` (one fifth of the entire duration). So, if we give `6 seconds` to the entire animation, `1.2s` will be used for movement and `4.8s` will be used for delay. You can play with it to get more accurate numbers.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%, 40%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    60%, 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
    0%, 40% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    60%, 100% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
.wrapper a:last-child div {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
}
```

## Snippet

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%, 40% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    60%, 100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
    0%, 40% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    60%, 100% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper a:first-child div{
  position: absolute;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  top: 13px;
  left: 13px; 
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wrapper a:last-child div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 6s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><div></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div></div></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although it works fine in my JS BIN sample, when applied to my actual work it shows some weird behavior. There is no animated movement in the 2nd and 4th rotation. Any idea?

Comment: This is with the actual images I am using. Please take a look at this [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ULiFoyo/11/edit)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37415/discussion-between-itay-and-seong-lee)

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%,10%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    90%,100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
```

Though, it doesn't allow for exact timing, it could do roughly what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

For regular rotation, you can use

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    12.5%, 25% {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);} 
    37.5%, 50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);} 
    62.5%, 75% {-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);} 
    87.5%, 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```