# React.JS: Sequence of timed state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple web app with one parent component and three child components. The children are just div boxes that can change their background color from white to red based on their property **active**. The **animateChild()** function can be used to turn a specific child red and then white again after 1s.

My goal is to "play" an arbitrary sequence of child animations with a break of 1s between each animation. This should happen in the **animateSequence()** function.

My initial idea to accomplish that, was to use a for loop and call **animateChild(childNum)** in a **window.setTimeout()** at each iteration. However, this didn't work. I guess because setState() is asynchronous and several state changes get merged together.

What is the best way to accomplish a sequence (e.g. Child 1, Child 2, Child 3) of animations with a break time of 1s between each animation? Thank you very much

**Javascript Code:**

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var childStyle = "basic"; 
    if (this.props.active){
      childStyle += " active";
    }
    return (
        <div className={childStyle}></div>
    );
  }
}


class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstChildActive:false,
      secondChildActive:false,
      thirdChildActive:false,
    };
    this.animateChild = this.animateChild.bind(this);

  }


  animateChild(childNum){
    var childDict = ["firstChildActive","secondChildActive","thirdChildActive"];
    this.setState({[childDict[childNum]]: true}, function() {

        window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({[childDict[childNum]]: false});

        },1000);
    });
  }

  animateSequence(){
    // animate child 2, then child 1, then child 3, then child 1, etc.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="container">
      <Child active={this.state.firstChildActive}/>
      <Child active={this.state.secondChildActive}/>
      <Child active={this.state.thirdChildActive}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.basic{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.active{
  background: red;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/miga89/full/owgZea/

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjEmME?editors=0010

Comment: Did you already tried CSS animations? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812055/css-animation-with-time-interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also converted your Child Component into a Stateless Component, the solution was just use a simple setInterval.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEyVo

```
const Child = ({ isActive }) => {
    var childStyle = "basic"; 
    if ( isActive ) childStyle += " active";
    return <div className={ childStyle }></div>
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstChildActive  : false,
      secondChildActive : false,
      thirdChildActive  : false,
    };
  }

  animateSequence(){

    const TOTAL = 3;
    const CHILD_DICT = ["firstChildActive","secondChildActive","thirdChildActive"];

    let run = 0;

    var setActive = setInterval( () => {
      this.setState({ [CHILD_DICT[run]]: true });
      run = run + 1;
      if( run === TOTAL ) {
        clearInterval(setActive);
      }
    }, 1000)

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="container">
        <button onClick={ () => this.animateSequence() }>Run Sequence</button>
      <Child isActive={this.state.firstChildActive }/>
      <Child isActive={this.state.secondChildActive } />
      <Child isActive={this.state.thirdChildActive }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your this context is invalid in the callback of first setState.

```
var childDict = ["firstChildActive","secondChildActive","thirdChildActive"];
this.setState({[childDict[childNum]]: true}, function() {
```

Should be

```
var childDict = ["firstChildActive","secondChildActive","thirdChildActive"];
this.setState({[childDict[childNum]]: true}, () => {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want do that without button use componentDidMount method in prototype:

```
 componentDidMount(){
  this.animateSequence();
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="container">        
      <Child isActive={this.state.firstChildActive }/>
      <Child isActive={this.state.secondChildActive } />
      <Child isActive={this.state.thirdChildActive }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```