# html sections background image switching

Tags: html, css

practicing my html & css skills meanwhile making random stuff, although stuck on making images to switch in section, for example every 5 seconds image changes into other.

That's the section's html and css (if it's matter in this case)

HTMLS:

```
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</section>`
```

CSS:

```
 #showcase{
 min-height:400px;
 background:url('../img/img1.jpg') no-repeat 0 -400px;
 background
 text-align:center;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-bottom:#0B0B0B 3px solid;
  }

 #showcase h1{
 margin-top:100px;
 font-size:55px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }

 #showcase p{
 font-size:20px;
 }
```

P.S trying to make it responsive as much as I can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animation with time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812055/css-animation-with-time-interval)

Comment: Given the complexity of what you're asking which is very very low, i'm going to assume that you didn't put any effort in researching it, people here don't appreciate that, more importantly they don't appreciate `code this for me` which is basically what you're asking for.

Comment: It's fine, already figured it out! :)